# @Id fields with name different than 'id'

Tags: java, broadleaf-commerce

In admin module I created new entity with list of countries

```
   @OneToMany(targetEntity = CustomISOCountryImpl.class, mappedBy = "someEntity")
   @AdminPresentationCollection(friendlyName = "someEntityImpl_Countries", addType = AddMethodType.LOOKUP)
   private List<CustomISOCountryImpl> countries;
```

CustomISOCountryImpl inherits from ISOCountryImpl.
I set the AddMethodType as LOOKUP. Now, when I try to add only one country from a list all of them are being added. It is only temporary effect, as they don't get persisted (they vanish after page refresh). Moreover, when I try to delete one of them I get an error:

Could not find the primary key property (alpha2) in the passed entity with type: xxx.xxx.xxx.CustomISOCountryImpl

After a while of debugging I found out that the problem is that broadleaf expects field with anootation @Id and field 'id', but the @Id of ISOCountryImpl is of a String type and is named 'alpha2'.

Any idea how to work this around ?

Comment: Sounds like there's definitely a bug there. As a workaround, you could try to create an xref entity and then your collection field would be a collection of those xrefs. Then, you could use @AdminPresentationAdornedTargetCollection. Something similar to ProductImpl#crossSaleProducts could work. Your xref entity doesn't have to include a sort property or other properties, so you could omit those items and just simply reference your iso country entity.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't resolve the problem, I keep getting error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve attribute named id